# Properties of my view can't saved

Tags: ember.js, jquery-masonry

Can anybody help me understand why `this.get('property_1')` is always null? And How can I fix it?

> ```
> App.SomeView = Em.View.extend({
>     property_1: null,
>
>     didInsertElement: function() {
>         this.scheduleRefresh();
>     },
>
>     scheduleRefresh: function(){
>         Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.refresh);
>     }.observes('controller.filter_params'),
>
>     refresh: function(){
>
>         if (!this.get('property_1')) {
>             this.set('property_1', 'Hello');
>         }  
>     }
> });
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: can you setup a jsbin? from your posted code it's not very clear

Comment: Unfortunately I can't It will be many code. But I reduced code at the my example. When `controller.filter_params` updated method `refresh` is run. But between runs my propertie value don't saved

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above works just fine. [Take a look at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/nL9Tr/). Is it possible that you are trying to retrieve the `property_1` view property from the controller? If so, you would want to define the property on the controller and bind to it from the view.

Comment: Code on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/87hPk/) have same problem (I added console.log and it wrote`null`) It seems it misunderstanding from my side.
What must I will do to be able get value from the property into `refresh` function?

Comment: The issue in that sample is that you are logging the property before it gets set. If you move the trace to below the `if` statement then it should log the desired value.